# How to fetch all ID which has duplicate data in another column using DBContext in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a table like this:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | John |
| 4 | Stephen |
| 5 | Peter |
| 6 | Ray |
| 7 | Tim |

I then have a repository class that holds `DbContext` methods:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
        private readonly DbFactory _dbFactory;

        public Repository(DbFactory dbFactor)
        {
            _dbFactory = dbFactor;
        }

        public void Add(T entity)
        {
            _dbFactory.DbContext.Add(entity);
        }

        public Task<T> GetByIdAsync(long id)
        {
            return _dbFactory
                .DbContext
                .FindAsync<T>(id)
                .AsTask();
        }
}
```

Now I want to include another method in this class to fetch all IDs having similar names. If I pass in some ID, it should fetch all the other IDs that share the same name.

For example, if I pass in `ID = 1`, it should fetch these rows:

| ID |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Which existing method in `DbContext` in Entity Framework can I use to achieve this?

Comment: How would you write SQL to do that @Nisha?

Comment: i want use linq in the DBContext method like this : var query = from t1 in items
                    from t2 in items
                    where t1.Name== t2.Name && t1.Id == UserInputData.Id

Comment: By *having similar names* you really name: all rows with the **identical** name - correct? "Similar" in English doesn't really mean "identical" - you're not being very clear in that regard....

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the simplest thing, and easiest to understand: Two queries...

```
var name = context.People
    .Where(x => x.Id == id)
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .Single();
var otherIds = context.People
    .Where(x => x.Name == name && x.Id != id)
    .Select(x => x.Id)
    .ToList();
```

To self-join, it gets a bit uglier:

```
var query = context.People
    .Where(x => x.Id == id)
    .Join(context.People,
        p1 => p1.Name,
        p2 => p2.Name,
        (p1, p2) => new { P1Id = p1.Id, P2Id = p2.Id })
    .Where(x => x.P1Id != x.P2Id)
    .Select(x => x.P2Id)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your input parameter always id? or you can change it to the string name?

```
public async Task<T> GetIdBySimilarNameAsync(string name)
{
        return await _dbFactory
            .DbContext
            .Where<T>(x => x.name  == name)
            .Select(p => new {p.Id}).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: thank you..the input parameter should be ID. But I will try this method too